# Breakpoints in custom theme not showing in the "group breakpoints" field

Tags: 8, theming

I'm having a problem that i simply can't find how to resolve it. I've created a custom theme based on the "claro" from drupal core. Then I've installed the modules Breakpoints + Responsive Image.

I've renamed the theme as "nescau", and created a new breakpoints file. "nescau.breakpoints.yml". I've created 2 breakpoints: "nescau.mobile", and "nescau.desktop" to test the module.

The problem is when I go this url:

http://nescaumeeg/admin/config/media/responsive-image-style/add

so I can add image styles for the breakpoints, the nescau.breakpoints doesn't show in the field "group".

[image: problem example]

In the image example, there should be a "nescau" inside that field, so I can choose an image style for each breakpoint.

I've tried searching on the web, but found nothing. I'll be glad if someone could help me.

**EDIT**

I'm using a custom theme that has the base theme as "claro" from core.

This is the breakpoints file.

```
nescau.mobile:
  label: mobile
  mediaQuery: '(min-width: 0px)'
  weight: 0
  multipliers:
    - 1x
    - 2x
nescau.desktop:
  label: desktop
  mediaQuery: 'all and (min-width: 800px)'
  weight: 1
  multipliers:
    - 1x
    - 2x
```

Comment: Hi Jean, could you please also post your `nescau.breakpoints.yml` contents here. Also: You did clear the cache, right?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've cleared caches already, but nothing. I've also edited my post with the contents from the breakpoints file.

Comment: And you sure enabled the new theme already and set it as default?

Comment: Can you please try having the multipliers in one single line, like `- '1x, 2x'`?

Comment: the breakpoints file syntax is correct (only the mobile mediaQuery should be changed to `(max-width: 799px)` in order to avoid overlaps) - as @leymannx mentioned I also think it could be, that the nescau theme is not enabled in the side.